# How to copy selected elements in a list to another list using stream

Tags: java, list

I have a list that has elements like:

```
public class Element1 {
    private Long id;
    private String Uid;
    private Long description;
    private Long number;
}
```

and another object like:

```
public class Element2 {
    private Long id;
    private String Uid;
}
```

I have list of Element1 and want to create Elements2 from Element1:

```
List<Element1> element1List = getElement1List();
List<Element2> element2List = new ArrayList<>();
for(Element1 element1 : element1List) {
    Element2 element2 = new Element2();
    element2.setId(element1.getId());
    element2.setUid(element1.getUid());
    element2List.add(element2);
}
```

I am looking for doing this in a simpler way, maybe using stream(). What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `stream().map()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this just by `stream().map()` but I defined a constructor for Element2 Class:

```
element2List = element1List.stream().map(element -> new Element2(element.getId(), element.getUid())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```